# UWP: Two Splitview pane

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, splitview, uwp-xaml

I am currently building app for Windows 10 using UWP, `XAML` and `C#`. I have an app, in which I need to have a menu, and a left pane. See this example of left menu :

[image: TheNextWeb - showing Square]

*Image - The Next Web*

The pane needs to be always open. This is what I currently have in my `MainPage.xaml`:

```
<SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"  IsPaneOpen="False" 
               CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="200">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <StackPanel Background="Gray">
                <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;"
                    Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="HamburgerButton_Click"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="HomeButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE10F;"
                    Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="HomeButton_Click"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Accueil" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="CommisButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE716;"
                        Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="CommisButton_Click"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Commis" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="CommentsButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE8BD;"
                        Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="CommentsButton_Click"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Commentaires" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="SettingsButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE713;"
                        Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="SettingsButton_Click"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Paramètres" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <!-- My Content -->
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
```

I have tried to make another `SplitView.Pane` but it doesn’t succeed. I need a way to make a left panel, thats it!

Thanks

Comment: couldn't understand what you want to achieve.And only one `StackPanel` will suffice in `SplitView.Pane` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `SplitView.Content`, add another `SplitView`.

```
<SplitView.Content>
    <!-- My Content -->
    <SplitView x:Name="MyRisksPane" IsPaneOpen="True" OpenPaneLength="350" Background="White" DisplayMode="Inline">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <!-- Your SplitView.Pane content goes here -->
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame x:Name="FrameDetailPane"/>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</SplitView.Content>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't tinking this was possible.